# MYSQL MODIFY command crashes and loses connection

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to change the datatype of a column in one table and every time i try to perform the MODIFY command it returns "lost connection to MYSQL server during query". When I perform other command such as SELECT or DELETE it doesn't have this problem. Solutions?

Running out of the cloud, The issue only happens on this command. changing the datatype in the schema presentation doesn't appear to work(forward engineering and saving are not overwriting current data type).

```
ALTER TABLE courses
MODIFY  title tinyblob;
```

Comment: Do you have permission to ALTER? Is it timing out?

Comment: I found a solution. I was trying to go from a varchar(45) to a varchar(80) but it wasnt working so I had to wipe the table and then it worked. not the best solution but it works now.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a crash.  It seems more likely that, due to a large amount of existing data in the table, the operation is taking a long period of time, and your connection is timing out while the command is running.